# PHP: Creating big HTML-table efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, object, foreach, html-table

I'm making a HTML table based on certain information in my MySQL database. The tables I need from the database hold the data for rows (*rowid*, *rowname*), columns (*columnid*, *columnname*) and cell data. A table, that links IDs from rows and columns together (*cellid*, *rowid*, *columnid*, *somedata*).
The table looks something like this:

```
__________| column1  | column2  | column3  | ...
     row1 | somedata | somedata |          |
----------|----------|----------|----------|-----
     row2 | somedata |          | somedata |
----------|----------|----------|----------|-----
...       |          |          |          |
```

My approach was to use several nested foreach loops, something like this:

```
$rows = new Rows();        //These objects are containers for objects
$columns = new Columns();  //that hold some of the database data. 
$alldata = new Alldata();  //MySQL queries within these objects are irrelevant, I think. They already get the relevant data

$count = count($alldata);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

foreach ($columns->getColumns() as $column) {
    echo "<td>".$column->getColumnname()."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

foreach ($rows->getRows() as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row->getRowname()."</td>";

    foreach ($columns->getColumns() as $column) {
        $last = 1;

        foreach ($alldata->getAlldata() as $data) {
            if ($data->getCID() == $column->getID() & $data->getRID() == $row->getID()) { //If the column has data the related to the row
                echo "<td>".$data->getSomedata()."</td>";
                break;
            }
            if ($last == $count) { //if loop couldn't find any entries, it prints an empty cell
                echo "<td>&nbsp;<td>";
            }
            $last++
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Bruteforcing, obviously this is not very efficient method when there are several hundred rows of data on any table in the database and I don't like this. **Any ideas how to make this more efficient? Is there better way of creating a table like I need?**

EDIT:
Pondering about this problem for a week has finally given me some answers. It was so simple!
I did a slight modification to my *Column* object class. Previously, my code went through all possible entries on *celldata* table in the database. Now *Column* object gets an array of *celldata* where *columnid's* match and I can do the comparison using only that data.

```
$rows = new Rows();
$columns = new Columns();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

foreach ($columns->getColumns() as $column) {
    echo "<td>".$column->getColumnname()."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

foreach ($rows->getRows() as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row->getRowname()."</td>";

    foreach ($columns->getColumns() as $column) {
        $last = 1;
        $count = count($column->getAlldata());

        foreach ($column->getAlldata() as $data) {
            if ($data->getCID() == $column->getID() & $data->getRID() == $row->getID()) {
                echo "<td>".$data->getSomedata()."</td>";
                break;
            }
            if ($last == $count) {
                echo "<td>&nbsp;<td>";
            }
            $last++
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Much faster, although still bruteforcing but there's less amount of data to go through. Of course, now the problem is that *Column* objects may do quite a lot of MySQL queries, depending on how many *Columns* there are.

Comment: Are the row and column IDs guaranteed to be in numerical order?

Comment: @eggyal rows and columns are sorted by their name, so no.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that the data fetched from MySQL is correctly ordered in `$alldata` by joining the tables and specifying an `ORDER BY` clause in your query:

```sql
SELECT   data.*
FROM     data RIGHT JOIN rows USING (rowid) RIGHT JOIN columns USING (columnid)
ORDER BY rowname, columnname;
```

Then you only need to output each cell in order:

```
echo '<table>';

echo '<thead>'
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
foreach ($columns->getColumns() as $column) {
    echo '<th scope="col">', htmlentities($column->getColumnname()), '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
$data = $alldata->getAlldata();
foreach ($rows->getRows() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<th scope="row">', htmlentities($row->getRowname()), '</th>';
    foreach ($columns->getColumns() as $column) {
        $d = each($data);
        echo '<td>', ($d ? htmlentities($d[1]->getSomedata()) : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: if it's really big table and you want to try some micro optimization you can try using comma "," instead of concatenation "." in your echo statements.

Comment: That MySQL query seemed to do pretty good job. As I examined what some of the objects hold, there were some objects with null values. Perhaps that was the thing I was looking for. However, your code doesn't go work with mine. The problem lies in $d = $data->getSomedata(). $data is not an object but an array so it can't use that function.

Comment: @eggyal: Did it? Function getAlldata() gets an array of objects and my third foreach loop (`foreach ($alldata->getAlldata() as $data)`) goes through the objects in that array. The objects inside the array represents rows in the database.

Comment: Yes. As I said, `$alldata->getAlldata()` gets an array of objects. I can't use `getSomedata()` function on that array. I have to break it apart first in order to use the `getSomedata()` function. Just to make it clear, _Alldata_ and _Data_ are separate objects and they don't share any functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this would be to rewrite the query for `$alldata` so that it is in the order you want like eggyal suggested. If you can't do that for some reason, you could iterate through `$alldata` in the beginning and create a properly indexed array from it. Something like this:

```
$ordereddata = array();
foreach($alldata as $d) {
    $ordereddata[$d->getCID()][$d->getRID()] = $d->getSomedata();
}
```

Now you can replace your `foreach($alldata)` loop with this:

```
if(isset($ordereddata[$column->getID()][$row->getID()])) {
    echo "<td>{$ordereddata[$column->getID()][$row->getID()]}</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
```

Comment: I have full access to any part of the code. I actually tried something similar before but it didn't work. I got all the data but I couldn't print empty cells. Every cell just aligned to the left with no space between them.